# What is a docker container from Linux's point of view?

Tags: linux-kernel, docker, cgroups, container

A docker container is a concept understood by docker daemon.
What is a docker container from Linux's point of view?

1. You can stop, kill and destroy a container. Is a container itself a
   process?
2. Is a docker container exactly a cgroup?  or can be identified by a
   cgroup?

   Is a docker container exactly the group  of processes running in the
   container?

   How can I find out  cgroup and container (ID) from each other?

Thanks.

Comment: It's really not a kernel concept, so from Linux's view it's simply some processes. Unlike other Unix, kenerl just offer enough functionality to build a container technology, while container is an application-defined concept in Linux systems, it purely depends on which container technology you're referring to(Different container technology use kernel functionality differently, docker is not the same as flatpack, nor the same as systemd-nsspawn). So do killing, stopping, destroying actions.

Comment: Read [this post by Jessie Frazelle on what containers are and are not](https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/containers-zones-jails-vms/), and watch the start of [this talk by Matt Turner](https://youtube.com/watch?v=zJnYuFsLHfY) which has a great explanation of how namespaces fit together to “provide” containers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A container isn't defined in Linux.  It's purely a construct of the application you use to launch it.

Typically there are a number of features that define a container:

- Namespace isolation

  - mount
  - process
  - UTS
  - ... etc
- Cgroup resource limitations
- seccomp restrictions

  - stop apps being able to reach syscalls

And so on.

Containers aren't defined by cgroups, so the rest of your questions are meaningless.  The *primary* construct of a container are the namespace features of `clone(2)`.

Comment: (1) Could you be specific about "The primary construct of a container are the namespace features of clone(2)"? (2) you can stop, kill and destroy a  container, similarly to a process. If a container isn't a process or a group of processes, what is "stop, kill and destroy a  container" from Linux's point of view?

Comment: Stopping docker containers is a _docker_ feature, not an OS feature.  There is no "Linux point of view".  Linux cares about things like namespaces, not containers.  I can't be more specific than `clone(2)` because that's the _core_ functionality docker uses!

Comment: A container also has a root (init), process (process 0 in its pid namespace). All other processes in the container, are descendants of it. If these processes die, then the container is nearly gone.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor It'd be PID 1, and that happens because the creation of the container normally includes `CLONE_PID` in the arguments to `clone(2)` to create a new PID namespace.  This is a feature of namespaces.

Comment: @StephenHarris sorry out by one error ☹